# Find homography matrix by 4 displacement points

Tags: computer-vision, homography

I have trained a model which could find out the displacement points of 4 corresponding pixels according to [Deep image homography estimation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03798.pdf). In other words, output of this paper do not give me 4 corresponding points but their displacement.

Example :

4 corresponding points:

```
p1 <-> p1', p2 <-> p2', p3 <->p3', p4 <-> p4'
```

Displacement of 4 corresponding points(output of the model):

```
(p1'.x - p1.x, p1'.y-p1.y), (p2'.x - p2.x, p2'.y-p2.y), (p3'.x - p3.x, p3'.y-p3.y), (p4'.x - p4.x, p4'.y-p4.y)
```

The paper say we could do 1-to-1 mapping from 4 replacement points to the 9 parameters homography matrix, but how?

I study DLT as the paper suggest, this algorithm need 4 corresponding points(8 pixels location) but not displacement of 4 corresponding points.

Comment: In my opinion if dont have locations of this displacement you have not enough data. Same displacements located in various image parts will produce different homographies.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question, you are asking how displacements can be generated without even having the pixel [correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_problem)s in the first place. This needs a bit of description over the assumptions of the paper.

As described in the abstract, given two images they estimate the [Homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision)) matrix which (under certain assumptions) fully describe the displacement of each pixel between two images.

```html
P<sup>2</sup><sub>i</sub> = HP<sub>i</sub><sup>1</sup>
```

In the formula above, *H* is a 3x3 matrix multiplied by P2 which is a point in the second image. This operation gives P1 which is its "transformed" position in the first image. Whenever a homography matrix is used to describe this transformation, it is assumed that the objects in the scene are so far such that they can be explained as such they live on a plane. That is the reason why a matrix is used to explain this transform. Since it can only describe an affine transform (i.e. translation, rotation, and skew) all of which are held under the assumption of the planar scene.

Getting back to your question, this transformation can be used to find the correspondence e.g. by rounding the *P1*   in the equation above Or finding the nearest neighbors in the first image which makes it no longer a one to one mapping since multiple *P2* can be mapped to one P1.

I am not sure if your question falls into my answer set. If it doesn't let me know so I can improve it.

Comment: In the conclusion, it is as @Kamil mentioned, I do not have enough of data. I guess I would just use the training image generation solution proposed by the paper to find the homography matrix, in most of the cases, resize the image to 320,240 and center crop it should work